# Method setSpanSizeLookup doesn't show two items in one row

Tags: android

I'm trying to view itmes in next order, like on the picture below:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/o9yGu.jpg

One item in first row and two items in second and again one item in 3-rd row and 2 itmes in 4-th row. I've writen this code:

```
GridLayoutManager layoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(this, 2, GridLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false);
    ((GridLayoutManager) layoutManager).setSpanSizeLookup( new GridLayoutManager.SpanSizeLookup() {
                @Override
                public int getSpanSize(int position) {
                    // 2 column size for first row
                    if((position % 2) == 0){
                        return 1;
                    } else
                    return 2;
                }
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Unfortunately the row that must contains 2 items has been mapping not correctly:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/o9yGu.jpg

Thanks a lot for help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change the `getSpanSize` method to below:

```
public int getSpanSize(int position) {
                // 2 column size for first row
                if((position % 3) == 0){
                    return 2;
                } else
                return 1;
            }
```

since we need to set each third item bigger than the others

Comment: it works. Can you please explain  this how it is working?

Comment: sure thing:
you are looking at your row, not your items! by that, I mean you tell the first item to be big and second item to be small and then again the third item to be big!!!!
to fix this we need to say only every third item should be big!!
that's what my code does.
if this explanation is not sufficient enough you can message me for more info

Comment: thanks for reply I have doubt in 

`if((position % 3) == 0)
{
    return 2;
}`
What does means of  return 2 when item position proper divisible by 3 ;. Is that it will display two element in row?

Comment: I know it's a bit tricky,since you have specified you GridLayoutManager columns= 2 layoutmanager will create a to columns in every row. so the returning value of the getSpanSize will specify the number of columns that item should use.

Comment: Ok suppose we have `position=3` and  `if((position % 3) == 0)` condition comes true. or we have  `return 2`; According to this there should be `2 items` at `position 3rd` But there is only `one item`. how this is possible?

Comment: you are half way correct.
as i have said the returning value (Ie: 2) means the amount of columns item of that position (ie: 3)  should take.
so for position 3 we will have a item that has size of two columns(2 items)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176538/discussion-between-sukhbir-and-seyed-jafari).